# possible determinants of permutations

Tags: linear-algebra, permutations, determinant

this is taken from Gilbert Strang's Linear Algebra book:

What are all the possible $4\times4$ determinants of $I + P_{even}$? (P - permutation matrix)

I seem to be stuck on this question except for the one fact that the diagonal is always going contain $1$'s and that even permutations themselves have determinant $1.$

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hint: eigenvectors of $P$ are also eigenvectors of $I+P$

Answer (score 2):

Decompose the permutation into cycles and consider the cycle lengths. There are five possibilities:

1. 1+1+1+1 (this notation means there are four 1-cycles). This is an even permutation and $P=I$. So, $\det(I+P)=2^4$.
2. 1+1+2. This is an odd permutation.
3. 1+3. This is an even permutation and $P$ is permutation similar to $\pmatrix{1\\ &0&1&0\\ &0&0&1\\ &1&0&0}$. Hence $\det(I+P)=2^2$.
4. 2+2. This is an even permutation and $P$ is permutation similar to $\pmatrix{0&1\\ 1&0\\ &&0&1\\ &&1&0}$. Hence $\det(I+P)=0$.
5. 4 . The permutation is a 4-cycle, hence odd.

In conclusion, $\det(I+P)$ can be $\color{red}{0,\,2^2}$ or $\color{red}{2^4}$.

Comment: Quite optimal, +1.